# Changing cursor in CursorAdapter is not properly updating list item views

Tags: android, android-listview, cursor, android-cursoradapter, notifydatasetchanged

This question is very similar to many other questions on StackOverflow, but I think it merits its own post due to a difference in approach compared to other questions here.

I have a custom adapter that extends `CursorAdapter`.  I'm updating the data and calling `notifyChange` on the appropriate URI in order to refresh the cursor.  In debugging, I can see that this is working properly.

Unfortunately, my list views are not being recreated.  The reason that I need them to be recreated is because of my `newView` implementation on the adapter:

```
public View newView(final Context context, final Ingredient ingredient, final ViewGroup parent) {
    final int layout = ingredient.isOwned() ? LAYOUT_OWNED : LAYOUT_UNOWNED;
    final View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layout, null);

    // ... ViewHolder magic

    return view;
}
```

The problem is that calling `notifyChange` is updating the list data, but it is not recreating the view that I need via `newView`.

Here are some other things I tried that equally did not work:

- called `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after the data was updated.
- called `contentResolver.notifyChange(...)` followed by `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after the data was updated.
- called `adapter.changeCursor(newCursor)` followed by `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.
- called `view.invalidate()` on the specific list item that changed.

Any other suggestions on how to approach this?

**Edit**: I may altogether just be taking the wrong approach.  I misunderstood the recycling of views within adapters, and I see that the wrong type of view is being used when recycled.  As such, I'll probably need to go about styling my views using another approach.  The reason I was taking this approach in the first place is due to my desire to use styles, which can't be set programmatically other than inflating a view as [explained in this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142067/android-set-style-in-code).  I'm open to approaches that will take advantage of that answer while properly recycling list item views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up figuring out the problem based upon [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12181908/107277).  I needed to override `getItemTypeCount` and `getItemViewType` on my adapter.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return getItem(position).isOwned() ? 1 : 0;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}
```